# how to change time from "1400" to "2:00pm"

Tags: php

I have a database that lists time as "100", "200", "1000", "1400", etc. What is the easiest way to turn this into something like "2:00 pm"? I really don't want to use a bunch of conditional operations if I don't have to.

Comment: you are trying to show 100 as 1:00pm ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the value to time using AM/PM you can do as

```
$time = '1400';

echo date('h:i A',strtotime($time));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php `date()` function. You can convert it to any format you want. [Here is the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

---

For you case, you can do do:

```
<?php

    $time = 1400;
    echo date('h:i A', strtotime($time));

?>
```

This will print out `2:00 PM`

---

#[Check it out live here][2]